# Match globs in browser-based JavaScript

Tags: javascript, glob

In browser-based JavaScript, is it possible to perform glob pattern matching?

For illustrative purposes **only**, I mean a glob like this: `**/*.{eot,otf,ttf,woff,woff2}`, which could be matched against a URL. Or perhaps something similar to match against a list of files, etc.

To reiterate, this is in the browser: so no Node, npm packages, SPA libraries, etc.

Comment: Most JS libraries would run in the browser, whether they are installed via npm or not and were originally written for SPAs or not. And yes, this is possible, why wouldn't it? Please share your research and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. I'm unsure what more to add. It's a traditional server-rendered app. I need to perform a glob match in the browser. I was hoping that in modern JavaScript there may be a way to perform glob matching without libraries. It's possible to perform regex in the browser, I was hoping for globs too. If impossible, ok.

Comment: Well if you want to do it without libraries, write the code yourself. If you already know that it is possible with a library, it's also possible without a library (just more work).

Comment: @jantimon Exactly. For this particular system, which is ASP.NET Core, I'm currently not using any npm packages, or webpack or anything. For this one small requirement - globs - I might have to set up an entire js toolchain. I wanted to avoid that. I was hoping that just like it's possible to process regex natively (i.e. in the browser, without packages), there might be a way to do that for globs. Modern JS has new features all the time... I guess not. That's fine. Was better to ask than to remain ignorant.

Comment: You can now use esm npm libraries directly from the browser without build step (at least in theory):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: @jantimon Interesting, thanks!

Comment: @jantimon It's not about the involvement of libraries - questions asking about the usage of libraries, or even about how to build something without libraries, are fine. But questions asking whether something "is possible" without libraries just don't make sense.

Comment: @lonix It's still not clear to me whether you meant to ask "How to implement glob-matching functionality without a library?" or "Is there a web API in browsers that helps with glob matching?". And if it's the former, it's not clear whether you need to support arbitrary glob patterns, or just want something to match the particular glob pattern you've given as an example.

Comment: @Bergi. I think the latter. Imagine I wanted to match regex and didn't know about `Regex`; the answer would be to use that (or search one of the countless other SO questions for that). Well, since JS is evolving so quickly these days, I was hoping there's some new way inside the browser to do that. I know how to use external packages, I wanted to avoid that. I was hoping for built-in glob support. Maybe we can revisit this question in a few years. :)

Comment: @lonix then please [edit] to clarify

Comment: @lonix Well it's not exactly glob patterns but there is an [experimental URL pattern API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL_Pattern_API)

Comment: @Bergi Very interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different solutions - but you will probably have to use a npm library.

For example [glob-to-regexp (npm)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob-to-regexp) - which has over 20mio weekly downloads (Nov 2023)

`glob-to-regexp` will convert a glob pattern expression into a regular expression:

```js
var globToRegExp = require('glob-to-regexp');
var re = globToRegExp("**/*.{eot,otf,ttf,woff,woff2}");
re.test("/this/is/an/example/a.woff"); // true
```

you could also convert a regexp into a string on the server or during build time:

```js
var globToRegexp = require("glob-to-regexp")
const re = globToRegexp("**/*.{eot,otf,ttf,woff,woff2}");
const reString = re.toString();
// -> "/^.*\\/.*\\.\\{eot\\,otf\\,ttf\\,woff\\,woff2\\}$/"
```

in the browser you can use the string of the regexp and turn it back into a regular expression:

```js
const re = new RegExp("/^.*\\/.*\\.\\{eot\\,otf\\,ttf\\,woff\\,woff2\\}$/");
re.test("/this/is/an/example/a.woff"); // true
```

Comment: Thanks. If it can't be done natively, I'll use to an npm package.

Comment: @lonix Any npm package runs native js code

Comment: @Bergi I understand. I meant natively in the browser without external packages. In the environment I'm using I wanted to avoid npm.

Comment: @lonix npm is not the only way to install libraries, just a more comfortable and automatable one.

Comment: @Bergi I think you understand what I'm after. We're arguing semantics now.